# How do I evaluate View.body in XCTests?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xctest

I want to write a simple XCTest such as:

```
var actualCount = 0

let view = HStack {
  ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
    Text("Test").onAppear { actualCount += 1 } 
  }
}

let _ = view.body

XCTAssertEqual(actualCount, 3)
```

The problem is I get the syntax error:

> error: value of type 'HStack<ForEach<Range, Int, some View>>' has no member 'body'

If I try to wrap it in a custom View and then call `.body`, it does run, but it doesn't execute the code in `onAppear`.

If I try to keep it as an `HStack` and get it to run by adding `extension View { var body: some View { body } }`, I get a runtime error:

> Fatal error: body() should not be called on HStack<ForEach<Range, Int, ModifiedContent<Text, _AppearanceActionModifier>>>

Is there any way to force the body of a view tree to be evaluated for testing purposes?

Comment: How about doing this with UI testing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a better method, but you can place the `View` in a `UIHostingController`, and then call the [`_render(seconds:)`](https://gist.github.com/Cosmo/8349dc9957e8e27ae3d3bd0ffe43a250#file-swiftui-interface-swift-L1286) method:

```
final class MyTests: XCTestCase {
  func test() {
    var actualCount = 0

    let view = HStack {
      ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
        Text("Test").onAppear { actualCount += 1 } 
      }
    }

    UIHostingController(rootView: view).forceRender()

    XCTAssertEqual(actualCount, 3)
  }
}

extension UIHostingController {
  fileprivate func forceRender() {
    _render(seconds: 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you received is expected. Simply constructing a structure does not mean it will trigger any logic. The view needs to be used by the rendering pipeline (or layout pipeline at least) to trigger any events on it. To do so you may need to add this view into some window or view controller to force the layout and possibly rendering. Although possible I believe it is not something you should do when writing tests.

You need to avoid doing anything related to any specific type of views within your tests. If you expect a certain behaviour from a view related to your data model you need to mock that behaviour.
When writing tests you can expect behaviour but not rely on it. You should always try and avoid using Views or remote API access and such.

I assume that what you wrote in the example is not your real scenario. Your real scenario would look something like this:

```
let viewModel = MyViewModel()
let view = MyView(viewModel: viewModel)
view.showTexts(["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"])
XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.shownViewsCount, 3)
```

So somewhere a mocked version of your view should be defined, maybe backed up by a protocol

```
protocol MyViewInterface {
    init(viewModel: MyViewModelInterface)
    func showTexts(_ texts: [String])
}

class MockedMyView: MyViewInterface {
    let viewModel: MyViewModelInterface

    init(viewModel: MyViewModelInterface) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    func showTexts(_ texts: [String]) {
        viewModel.shownViewsCount += texts.count // Or whatever the expected logic is
    }
}
```

If on the other hand you are actually interested in writing UI tests then you should probably just use the actual UI testing and check that the 3 texts are rendered and accessible on the screen on a simulated device rather then checking that through your view model.

Having both, unit tests and UI tests will ensure you have sufficient coverage and that your test actually tests your own code and not someone else's (Like Apple View).